# Getting 'Failed to Load Resource: the Server Responded with a Status of 401' Error When Accessing OpenAI API with Correctly Configured Secret

Tags: reactjs, yaml, github-pages, vite, openai-api

I'm experiencing an issue where I get a 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401' error when trying to access the OpenAI API. I have configured the 'VITE_SOME_KEY' secret correctly in GitHub, and I'm using 'process.env.VITE_SOME_KEY' to access the API key in my code. However, I still encounter this error. Do you have any insights on what might be causing it or how to resolve it? I´m deploying in github pages and using Secrets for the api key.

Deploy.yml

```
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 16

      - name: Install dependencies
        uses: bahmutov/npm-install@v1

      - name: Build project
        run: npm run build

      - name: Upload production-ready build files
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: production-files
          path: ./dist

  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: production-files
          path: ./dist

      - name: Set up Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 16

      - name: Configure environment variables
        env:
          VITE_SOME_KEY: ${{ secrets.VITE_SOME_KEY }}
        run: |
          # Aquí puedes acceder a la API key a través de la variable de entorno VITE_SOME_KEY
          echo "Mi API key es $VITE_SOME_KEY"

      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: ./dist
```

app.jsx
`const API_KEY = process.env.VITE_SOME_KEY;`

I have configured the 'VITE_SOME_KEY' secret correctly in GitHub, but you are still encountering a 'Failed to Load Resource: the Server Responded with a Status of 401' error when attempting to access the API.